# "You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>", but Link is inside BrowserRouter

Tags: react-router-dom

As the title describes, I am getting the error for reasons I don't understand. I am using create-react-library, which may be somehow affected things. I copied all the code from my example project (in which there are links inside of a BrowserRouter) into a new folder, and while the issue doesn't come up in the original directory, the copied code throws the error. Any ideas?

```
ReactDOM.render(
 <BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
   <App /> // All the Links and Switches are in here
 </BrowserRouter>
, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: there's not enough info here to diagnose the problem. you are correct, this error should not occur if there are no links anywhere else. I don't normally recommend this, but can you link the code in github or something so we can try running it to see if we get the same error?

Comment: @azium there must have been some file corruption when I copied the files over, maybe because I did it through the Atom editor's UI? I copied again and everything worked. Sorry to bother you with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the files were getting corrupted, most likely because I was copying through Atom's UI.